# VBA Each Excel Cell as Bullet point in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to take the information in a range of cells and have each cell display as a bullet point within powerpoint.

For example

Cell A1 = My Sample Text 1 
Cell A2 = My Sample Text 2 
Cell A3 = My Sample Text 3

I want each to be bulleted in powerpoint like so.

- My Sample Text 1
- My Sample Text 2
- My Sample Text 3

The main point I want to get across is the number of cells is dynamic, sometimes I will have 3, other times I might have 5, etc. which is why I am using CurrentRegion.

Here's What I have so far

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
For Each Cell In Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Cells
ppSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=400, _
        Top:=150, _
        Width:=350, _
            Height:=50).TextFrame.TextRange.Paste
ppSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Paste.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = ppBulletUnnumbered

Next Cell
```

Any thoughts on why this may not be working?

Comment: Are you getting any output? Why are you copying the currentregion before your `For Each`? Shouldn't you copy each cell in the loop and then paste it as a bullet point in a shape you create on the PowerPoint slide?

Comment: @Dan all of my cells are combined into one long string which is placed into one bullet.

Comment: That's not what the code is trying to do, though.  For each cell in current range you are adding a textbox, which I assume is a bullet.  Also, putting `ppSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Paste.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = ppBulletUnnumbered` in your loop means that that you are repeatedly assigning `ppBulletUnnumbered` to the same shape property.  If you truly only want one bullet then you need to put that outside of your loop and only assign it once.

Comment: Here's another thing: `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
For Each Cell In Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Cells` is saying that you are copying the cell range associated to A1, then looping for every cell within that copied range.  I think you need to pick one or the other, grab all the cells or loop through them.  Not both.

Answer (score 1):

Declare "Cell" as a Range Object, and add something like this if you haven't:

```
Dim Cell As Range
Dim cellvalue As String

'{loop} 
For Each Cell in Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    cellvalue = Cell.Value
    ppSlide.shapes'.... use cellvalue for bullet
Next
'{end loop}
```